# How can I prevent sqlite3 (with Python 2.7) from inserting null bytes every other character?

Tags: python, sqlite

I want to use the REGEXP operator in my sqlite queries, so I implemented a regexp function:

```py
import sqlite3
import re

def regexp(pattern,string):
        print('(pattern,string) = ', pattern,string)
        try:
                regex = re.compile(pattern,re.I)
                return regex.search(string) is not None
        except Exception,e:
                print(e)
                return False

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
conn.create_function('REGEXP',2,regexp)
cursor = conn.cursor()
pattern = 'bc'
print('pattern =',pattern,)
cursor.execute("SELECT 'abc' REGEXP ? ;",(pattern,))

if (cursor.fetchone() == (1,)):
        print('Regex matches')
else:
        print('Regex does not match')

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

If I run this in Python 2.7 (which I'm supposed to use for this project), I get the following:

```
> ('pattern =', 'bc')  
> ('(pattern,string) = ', u'b\x00', u'a\x00b')
> Regex does not match
```

I end up with strings with their length unchanged if we count the null bytes, but they effectively only contain the fist half of the original characters. I can't figure out why.

Running the same code in Python 2.6, it works as expected:

```
> ('pattern =', 'bc')
> ('(pattern,string) = ', u'bc', u'abc')
> Regex matches
```

How can I make this work in Python 2.7 ?

I guess a workaround would be to double each character in my strings before sending them to cursor.execute, then remove the null bytes in the regexp function, but I would like a cleaner solution if it exists.

Comment: If you're using python 2, you should add a future statement if you're using print like a function. Anyways, this works on my machine(WSL Debian, Python 2.7.18), so I suspect this is probably some windows encoding issue. Can you provide more details about your environment?

Comment: I'm running this on a CentOS 6.10, with Python 2.7.13 and 2.6.6

Comment: If you have embedded nulls in your string, that's a strong hint that it's UTF-16 encoded.

Comment: Interesting. How should I handle that ?